# Is asking about retail availability of a phone REALLY an Android question?

Tags: discussion

I am an Android enthusiast who owns an Archos 43 Internet Tablet, which doesn't include any 3G/4G or phone capability out of the box.

I want to learn more about Android, but some of the questions on this site seem to be very phone-centric, such as [When will Google Nexus S be available in Belgium (Europe)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4149/when-will-google-nexus-s-be-available-in-belgium-europe), [Can I get Nexus S in Canada?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4068/can-i-get-nexus-s-in-canada), [What are the best android phones available in India?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/867/what-are-the-best-android-phones-available-in-india)

I'm just wondering if there is a way to filter this stuff out if it really does belong here.  I'm interested in the OS, not someone's phone buying decisions.

Comment: Your question here has prompted discussions as to what is/is not appropriate for this site: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/246/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-ask-here http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/247/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-not-ask-here

Comment: These surely fit perfectly under the "Too Localized" close criteria - "This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time" by definition they're only important for a short period of time, and only ever going to be correct for one network/region/country.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with you. I have been closing the most egregious examples, but the rest of the community doesn't seem to mind them so much. Otherwise there'd be flags on them and/or close votes.

No, I don't think they belong here. Unfortunately, they're a large percentage of the questions we get.

Comment: Is there a "Cell Phones" stackexchange site?

Comment: No. There was a Gadget.SE, but that was dropped. Someone has proposed a mobile phone site on Area 51, but I don't think it's going to go very far.

Comment: @Al Everett: You are correct in closing these. Shopping advice is generally off topic (or should be). If the community doesn't seem to care, that does not bode well for the future of this system. They *have* to be made to care and understand what you do. Close and leave clear comments as to why, not to scold but to teach and inform. They should be voting, closing, and flagging, where needed. Mix up the comments to highlight the problem with the post and what *should* have happened (community self-moderation). If users don't start picking up on these "sign posts", the site will not survive.

Comment: @Robert: Can we add "Shopping Advice questions" under the "What questions should I *NOT* ask" section of the FAQ?  We get quite a few of these and I don't think it's very obvious to new users that this is outside the scope.

Comment: @Matt: Sure. That section is not editable directly, but see how Super User's FAQ listed their off-topic subjects: http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: @Robert:  I like that much better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a shopping question and should not be allowed.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: I have closed the two questions mentioned in the OP that hadn't already been closed.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should allow the question if is Android centric.

For example, I often have discussions with people like: what is the latest version of android available on a stock phone...

Comment: You're in the wrong spot. You want to share that at http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/246/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-ask-here